# is there any Python framework which collects system's intermediate results like logging?

Tags: python, logging, pickle

`logging` provides a good framework to collect information about states, debug info ... However, it is quite often that I need to record some intermediate results, and these results are often objects (one common way is to pickle them). If there any framework that can take care of the scoring process, i.e. handle the file name, which folder to store and different store level (like log level)?

Comment: I voted to keep open, there's a good answer, and it's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

sure here you go ... (people usually just roll their own for this sort of thing)

```
import pickle,os
class MyPickler:
     file = os.path.expanduser("~/.data.pickle")
     my_data = {}
     @classmethod
     def update(cls,key,obj,debugLevel=0):
        cls.data[key] = {"data":obj,"level":debugLevel}
     @classmethod
     def save(cls,debugLevel=10):
         pickle.dump(
                dict([(k,v) for k,v in my_data.items() if v["level"] <= debugLevel]),
                open(cls.file,"wb")
                )
     @classmethod
     def load(cls,debugLevel=11):
          cls.my_data = dict([(k,v) for k,v in pickle.load(open(cls.file,"rb")).items() 
                                  if v["level"] <= debugLevel])

MyPickler.update("some_key",some_object,5)
MyPickler.save()
```

as an aside **`json.dump`** is much faster than pickle ...

Comment: Could you add some docstrings?

Comment: you mean like what each function does? I tried to make it fairly clear from their names ... anyway its really just an example ideally he will modify it to suite his needs and he can add the doc strings

Answer (score 1):

I ve been using [shove](https://bitbucket.org/lcrees/shove/src) as a tool of choice to cache inttenmediate results to enhance speed of computation.

Simplest shove use case is this:

```
>>> from shove import Shove
>>> store = Shove()
```

after that you use store as a normal dictionary. You can configure shove to cache data in RAM and store it to preatty much any datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `shove`, there's also `joblib` and `klepto`.

`Joblib` provides caching in memory or on a file (using a memmap), and uses a decorator interface (instead of a dict).  `Klepto` provides both a dict-style interface as well as
a decorator interface, and has several backends for caching and archiving.  The backends aren't as extensive as `shove`, but `klepto` has a lot of flexibility in how it stores the results… it can use a pickle, json, a hash, some other encoding, etc.  `Klepto` also leverages `dill`, so it can pickle pretty much anything.

Here's `klepto` saving results to memory, using a hashing algorithm:

```
from klepto import lru_cache as memoize
from klepto.keymaps import hashmap
hasher = hashmap(algorithm='md5')

class Adder(object):
    """A simple class with a memoized method"""

    @memoize(keymap=hasher, ignore=('self','**'))
    def __call__(self, x, *args, **kwds):
        debug = kwds.get('debug', False)
        if debug:
            print ('debug:', x, args, kwds)
        return sum((x,)+args)
    add = __call__

add = Adder()
assert add(2,0) == 2
assert add(2,0,z=4) == 2          # cached (ignore z)
assert add(2,0,debug=False) == 2  # cached (ignore debug)
assert add(1,2,debug=False) == 3
assert add(1,2,debug=True) == 3   # cached (ignore debug)
assert add(4) == 4
assert add(x=4) == 4              # cached

plus = Adder()
assert plus(4,debug=True) == 4    # cached (ignore debug)
assert plus(2,0,3) == 5
assert plus(2,0,4) == 6
info = add.__call__.info()
assert info.hit == 5
assert info.miss == 5
cache = add.__call__.__cache__()
assert sorted(cache.values()) == [2,3,4,5,6]
```

`Klepto` can also store results in a database backend, and allow the user to pick
algorithms for when the in-memory cache gets dumped and loaded to the database.
Here's the dict-style interface for `klepto`:

```
from klepto.archives import sqltable_archive as sql_archive
#d = sql_archive('postgresql://user:pass@localhost/defaultdb', cached=False)
#d = sql_archive('mysql://user:pass@localhost/defaultdb', cached=False)
d = sql_archive(cached=False)

d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = '1'
assert d['a'] == 1
assert d['b'] == '1'

d['c'] = min
squared = lambda x:x**2
d['d'] = squared
assert d['c'] == min
assert d['d'](2) == squared(2)
```

With both `klepto` and `joblib`, you can also choose to store results on disk, with automatically created filenames or otherwise.

Joblib is here: https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/

Klepto is here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto